# Converting hours:minutes:seconds to hours:minutes in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a column `cr.crash_time` with the data type `time` in Postgres. It appears as 24hours:minutes:seconds. I don't need the seconds, because they're all :00. I'm seeking to truncate the seconds and return results that just appear as 24hours:minutes.

I've tried the following, none of which worked:

```
date_trunc('minute', cr.crash_time)
TO_CHAR(cr.crash_time, hh24:mi),
TO_CHAR(cr.crash_time, hh:mi),
cr.crash_time::TIME(hh:mi),
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `to_char(crash_time, 'HH24:MI')` should do it.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!